# Javascript adding variable to a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I've written the following function in Typescript:

```
public searchPosts(keyword ? : string): Post[] {
  return this._posts.filter(function(post) {
    if (post.title.search(new RegExp('money', 'gi')) >= 0) {
      return post;
    }
  });
}
```

It's working just fine but, I need to make it a little dynamic so that instead of hardcoded value i.e. money, I can put my keyword variable in RegExp (`new RegExp(keyword, 'gi')`). But doing so does not return anything even for 'money' as a keyword.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Replace `'gi'` with `keyword`? --- Hmm.

Comment: Why are you returning the post in the filter? I got it to work using ES6 `(keyword = '') => this._posts.filter(post => post.title.search(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi')) >= 0)`

Comment: replacing did not work. I'm returning post that matches the criteria?

Comment: the `filter` should return `true` or `false`

Comment: I believe filter function: `Returns the elements of an array that meet the condition specified in a callback function.`

Comment: yes `that meet the condition specified in a callback function`, when you have condition its result is `true` or `false` ... so better just return this `return (post.title.search(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi')) >= 0);`

Comment: The _callback_ should return a boolean, see [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you paste the whole function here that you managed to work?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed that is the whole function

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should work

```js
  var keyword = '345';
  var f = ['1234', '3456'].filter(function(post) {
    return (post.search(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi')) >= 0);
  });
  
  console.log(f);
```

This is your function in pure JS

```js
var posts = [{title: '1234'}, {title: '3456'}];

function searchPosts (keyword) {
  return posts.filter(function(post) {
    return (post.title.search(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi')) >= 0);
  });
}

console.log(searchPosts('345'));
```

If this doesnt work, the problem is somewhere else ;].

Comment: ```public searchPosts(keyword?: string): Post[] {
    return this._posts.filter(function(post) {
      return (post.title.search(new RegExp(keyword, 'gi')) >= 0);
    });
  }``` What am I missing here?

Comment: ```public searchPosts(keyword?: string): Post[] {
    return this._posts.filter(function(post) {
      return (post.title.search(new RegExp('money', 'gi')) >= 0);
    });
  }``` this gives me the desired result but as soon as I replace the search string with keyword it does not work. Even console.log for keyword is as expected. :/

Comment: I've edited my answer. Your function seems OK. As you can see in my answer when you provide a string to the function it returns the desired result, so it is working just fine. That's what I can help you with. If you provide the code in the Plunker, can try more.